# My system boots to command line

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

Version 12.04
Graphics: NVidia GT750M and Haswell integrated
After the splash screen, a terminal comes up instead of X. I tried nomodeset but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing sudo startx, and check if there are no errors. Did you install or update the drivers recently? It happened once when I tried to install ATI video driver, I just uninstalled it and things got normal again.